# Function elem without backticks not working

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have to create a boolean function in Haskell that receives a word (String) and a list of characters. The function has to verify that all chars in the list are included in the string. I made some research and found out that functions `all` and `elem` could be helpful.

Example:

```
word = "hello"
list = ['h','o','e']
```

My code looks something like this:

```
allCharBelong word list = all (`elem` word) list
```

I made some testing and it works perfectly (If you want to double-check that would be nice).

My question is: **Why when I take out the backticks in elem, the function don't work?**

Working: `` allCharBelong word list = all (`elem` word) list ``

Not working: `allCharBelong word list = all (elem word) list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`` (`elem` word) `` is an operator section that partially applies the second argument, it is equivalent to `\x -> elem x word` whereas `elem word` = `` (word `elem`) `` = `\x -> elem word x`. It helps to annotate expressions with types to figure out what's going on sometimes.

Comment: Is maybe another way to do the function that I need? (using composition, high-order and/or partial application)

Comment: @warty yes: ``(`elem` word) x = x `elem` word = (x `elem`) word = elem x word = flip elem word x``, so ``(`elem` word) = flip elem word``.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because whereas in the first case you have what it's called a "section", i.e. a partial application of an infix operator where -in this case- you fixed the second argument, in the second case you fix the first parameter.

```
ghci> :t elem "string"
elem "string" :: [[Char]] -> Bool
ghci> :t (`elem` "string")
(`elem` "string") :: Char -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding backticks makes the function infix. `elem` is a binary operator when used in infix form. Putting an argument before or after an infix operator determines which of the arguments we're applying to:

```
(`elem` word) === \char -> elem char word -- apply to second arg
(char `elem`) === \word -> elem char word -- apply to first arg
```

`elem` without the backticks is just a regular curried function:

```
elem char === \word -> elem char word -- can only apply partially to first arg
```

Answer (score 0):

`` (`op` val) `` is an (IMO quite nice, because the backticks are so unobstrusive for reading) alternative writing for `flip op val`: it allows you to partially apply a function in its second, rather than first, argument.

Such operator sections are of course more commonly used with functions that are already in infix form, e.g.

> Prelude> map (!!4) ["....Hello", "...Hello", "..Hello", ".Hello", "Hello"]
>   "Hello"
>   Prelude> map (/2) [10,20,30,40]
>   [5.0,10.0,15.0,20.0]